# Remapping numpy arrarys to dictionary

Tags: numpy, dictionary, reshape, remap

I want to remap a numpy array according to a dictionary.
Let us assume I have a numpy array with N rows and 3 columns. Now I want to remap the values according to its indices which are written in tuples in a dictionary.
This works fine:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
b = np.zeros(6).reshape(2,3)
print a
print A

dictt = { (0,0):(0,2), (0,1):(0,1), (0,2):(0,0), (1,0):(1,2), (1,1):(1,1), (1,2):(1,0) }

for key in dictt:
    b[key] = a[dictt[key]]

print b
a = [[0 1 2]
    [3 4 5]]

b = [[ 2.  1.  0.]
    [ 5.  4.  3.]]
```

Let us assume I have N rows, where N is an even number. Now I want to apply the same mapping (which are valid for those 2 rows in the upper example) to all the other rows.
Hence I want to have an array from:

```
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]]
```

to:

```
b = [[ 2.  1.  0.]
    [ 5.  4.  3.]]
    [[ 8.  7.  6.]
    [ 11.  10.  9.]]
```

Any ideas? I would like to do it fast since these are 192000 entries in each array which should be remapped.

Comment: In python2 or python3 ?

Comment: So the order that is defined in your dictionary is arbitrary? Or do you always want to mirror your data? Because there would be more efficient ways without using a dictionary then ... (numpy.fliplr)

Comment: Thanks fit the advices. It is Python 2.7. Unfortunately, the order is random not mirrored.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I would just use [::-1].

```
a = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
b = [item[::-1] for item in a]
>>> b
[[2, 1, 0], [5, 4, 3], [8, 7, 6]]
```

Comment: As said above: Because a is a numpy array, b = np.fliplr(a) should be the most efficient way.

Comment: I haven't checked it for efficiency, you are probably right.